# Mapbox configuration is not working. Can not pass access token

Tags: node.js, express, mapbox, geocoding

I'm trying to implement geocoding to my express app and I decided to use MapBox client API. However when I tried to configure it, it's still throwing following error. Please help me

```
Error: Cannot create a client without an access token
    at NodeClient.MapiClient (D:\NODE COURSE\Colt Steele\DerpCamp\node_modules\@mapbox\mapbox-sdk\lib\classes\mapi-client.js:25:11)
    at new NodeClient (D:\NODE COURSE\Colt Steele\DerpCamp\node_modules\@mapbox\mapbox-sdk\lib\node\node-client.js:7:14)
    at createNodeClient (D:\NODE COURSE\Colt Steele\DerpCamp\node_modules\@mapbox\mapbox-sdk\lib\node\node-client.js:24:10)
    at D:\NODE COURSE\Colt Steele\DerpCamp\node_modules\@mapbox\mapbox-sdk\services\service-helpers\create-service-factory.js:13:16
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\NODE COURSE\Colt Steele\DerpCamp\src\controllers\CampgroundController.js:6:18)
```

Here is my configuration

```
const Geocoding = require('@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/geocoding')
const map_token = process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN
const geocoder = Geocoding({accessToken: map_token})
```

**VERY IMPORTANT NOTE**

There is no space between MAPBOX_TOKEN and my actual api key in my `dev.env` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running the application locally, `process.env` will return `undefined`. This issue can be resolved using the [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package.

Installation:

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

Example usage:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv"); // Define the dotenv package
dotenv.config(); // Call the config function
```

The config function only needs to be called in the main file (commonly called `index.js`) and will allow `process.env` to work throughout the project.